# Is there an easy way to read unverified decimal values from a file?

Tags: c, validation, file-io, scanf

Let's say I have a file of decimal numbers which *should* be values that can fit in an `int`, but I want to programmatically verify the content of this file to check for overflows. Is there an easy way to check if any of the numbers will over flow an integer?

Ex. file -

```
name:  test.txt
value: 4343214321423142314
```

If I were to loop and do `fscanf(fd, "%d", &myint)` we would return a successful indication but the number stored in myint would be incorrect.

Likewise if I were to read it in to a character array `fscanf(fd, "%s", &mystr)` and blindly call `atoi(mystr)` it would return success but with an incorrect result.

Given the second example of reading it into a string it would be possible to do something like:

```
char buf[11] = {'\0'};
sprintf(buf, "%d", INT_MAX);

fscanf(fd, "%s", &mystr); 
if(strcmp(mystr, buf) > 0)
    // handle error case
```

but is there an easier way to do this without needing the extra array and string compare function?

Comment: Call `strtol`, check whether that reports an out-of-range error, and (if `int` is smaller than `long`) compare its result to `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [scanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) man page, the conversion would fail with `errno` set to

> ERANGE
>
> The result of an integer conversion would exceed the size that can be stored in the corresponding integer type.

in your case. So I'll just check the result of `scanf` or `fscanf` and use `errno`.

Comment: Actually I missed that note down there at the bottom about it setting `ERANGE`, that will work

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can read your integer into a string, and then use `strtol`. Then you have two solutions, according to the type of your result:

- `long`: if it returns `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX`, you can check `errno` against the value `ERANGE` to see whether the number overflows;
- `int`: if it returns a number greater than `INT_MIN` or smaller than `INT_MAX`, you can safely put your number in an `int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
fscanf(fd, "%d%n%c", &myInt, &pos, &nextChar);
```

Then check that `pos` is where you expect it to be and the next character is not a digit?

Comment: +1 for creativity, but that is another factor of 10 solution. If `INT_MAX == 2147483647` then I'd want `pos == 10`. A value of 3147483647 would therefore pass this check but fail to fit in an `int`.

Comment: @Mike - It will not. As the pos bit will be in the wrong place. It will fall short hence the next character will be an interger. The `%d` will give up or the whole thing just fails.

Comment: Then could you elaborate on your example? I just tried running it given a file with `3147483647` and I'm getting a `myInt == MAX_INT`, `pos == 10`, and `nextChar` is newline. I would expect `myInt` to be what was in the file (fails), `pos` to be `10` (success), and `nextChar` to be `'\n'` (success). Am I misunderstanding your example?

Comment: @Mike - Forgot to mention that you should also check for `MAX_INT`. If you get that value then most of your calculations is going out of the window. In engineering I think you should you about 70% of the number range of floats, doubles, longs and integers. The Victorians did summat similar and hence in the UK we still have bridges that are well over 100yrs but the stuff from the 60's are falling down!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `strtol()`; it has a well-defined behavior if the conversion is failing due to overflow. If you know that your incoming values are in fact unsigned, use `strtoul()`.